# ~all of which + having vs. have?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

We had exams three days ago, and there's a question I still don't get. We had to correct (but were not allowed to split into two sentences):

> Good papers do not merely review literature and then say something like "there are many different points of view, and all of which have something good to say."

I wrote:

> ... of view, all of which having something good to say.

The right answer was:

> ... of view, and all of them have something good to say.

Is my answer completely wrong, or can it work as well?

Comment: Your answer reads perfectly well. The "correct" answer is a simpler form and is seen more often.  Perhaps the test was about how to use "and" and your answer is "wrong" for that reason.

Comment: *Each of which* would be better than *all of which* - unless they had to be considered collectively and not individually.